# How to get started using SwiftMailer

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I wanna use swiftmailer to send the results of a form to a gmail account.

I'm new to php (and new to ubuntu), and in the stage of being (embarrasingly) lost even when reading the documentation.

Questions:

a) Where do I extract the library? I placed it on my desktop. Shouldn't it go in some apache folder?

b) How would a sample message sent to a gmail inbox would look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as there are permissions set so your webserver can read the directory, you can put this library where ever you like. So if your webserver serves pages from `/var/www/htdocs`, maybe you should put this at `/var/www/swift`. Then when you require the library in your application, you can:

```
require_once '/var/www/swift/lib/swift_required.php';
```

Then you can start using the library. For more information, check out the docs for a quick reference at:
http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html